# Shares of Lifecycle Livedata ViewModel with ViewBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-lifecycle, android-viewbinding

I'm still new to Kotlin.
So I want to try Lifecycle, LiveData, and ViewModel in my study project, using moviedb as its data. But since Android Kotlin Extensions dependency is deprecated, I have to use viewBinding as an alternative, but when I run the app, it goes error like this:

```
2022-06-28 11:39:19.935 25250-25250/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: id.kotlin.belajar, PID: 25250
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{id.kotlin.belajar/id.kotlin.belajar.presentation.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Base URL required.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3686)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3823)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2306)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7892)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Base URL required.
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.build(Retrofit.java:623)
        at id.kotlin.belajar.di.module.HomeModule$Companion.provideRetrofit(HomeModule.kt:25)
        at id.kotlin.belajar.di.module.HomeModule_Companion_ProvideRetrofitFactory.provideRetrofit(HomeModule_Companion_ProvideRetrofitFactory.java:29)
        at id.kotlin.belajar.di.module.HomeModule_Companion_ProvideRetrofitFactory.get(HomeModule_Companion_ProvideRetrofitFactory.java:21)
        at id.kotlin.belajar.di.module.HomeModule_Companion_ProvideRetrofitFactory.get(HomeModule_Companion_ProvideRetrofitFactory.java:11)
        at id.kotlin.belajar.di.module.HomeModule_ProvidesHomeDatasourceFactory.get(HomeModule_ProvidesHomeDatasourceFactory.java:29)
        at id.kotlin.belajar.di.module.HomeModule_ProvidesHomeDatasourceFactory.get(HomeModule_ProvidesHomeDatasourceFactory.java:13)
        at id.kotlin.belajar.presentation.HomeViewModel_Factory.get(HomeViewModel_Factory.java:27)
        at id.kotlin.belajar.presentation.HomeViewModel_Factory.get(HomeViewModel_Factory.java:11)
        at id.kotlin.belajar.di.factory.ViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelFactory.kt:13)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at id.kotlin.belajar.presentation.HomeActivity$viewModel$2.invoke(HomeActivity.kt:26)
        at id.kotlin.belajar.presentation.HomeActivity$viewModel$2.invoke(HomeActivity.kt:24)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at id.kotlin.belajar.presentation.HomeActivity.getViewModel(HomeActivity.kt:24)
        at id.kotlin.belajar.presentation.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.kt:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8285)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8264)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
```

So I want to know how to the said APIs using ViewBinding.
I need some shares or guides to do it. Thank you.

Link: https://github.com/muhammadwibisonojanuar/Coding-2.git

Comment: 1. Do not post Github links, always post relevant code. 2. Your crash is not because of `ViewBinding`, it's because you have not provided a Base Url to `Retrofit` in your `HomeModule`.

Comment: In your log it clearly states `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Base URL required.` check if u forgot to provide baseUrl

Comment: The Base_URL is provided in NetworkModule

Answer (score 0):

NetworkModule for Base_URL:

```
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import hu.akarnokd.rxjava3.retrofit.RxJava3CallAdapterFactory
import id.kotlin.belajar.BuildConfig
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
class Networkmodule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesHttpLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor{
        return HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = when (BuildConfig.DEBUG){
                true -> HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
                false -> HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
            }
        }
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesHttpClient(interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
            retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            addInterceptor(interceptor)
        }.build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesHttpAdapter(client: OkHttpClient): Retrofit.Builder {
        return Retrofit.Builder().apply {
            client(client)
            baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.createAsync())
        }
    }



}
```